# Overlaying shape over letters in CartoCSS

Tags: css, cartocss

I'm curious about styling options available in cartoCSS. I am wondering if it is possible to add shapes over specific letters of a maplabel (maybe this would be some type of vector overlay?) but I haven't found an example that seems to do this.

The reason I ask is that I'd like to create a Breaking Bad themed slippy map - for those who have seen the show, you may be familiar with the signature text-image.  The trademark text theme for the show is the first two letters of every word outlined in a green box, sort of like the periodic table.

An example image can be found here:

https://ntvb.tmsimg.com/assets/p8696131_b_h10_aa.jpg?w=1280&h=720

So, for example, if I had a label that said "Chicago" on my map, I'd like to have the "Ch" in a green box.  Anyway, just curious before I go too far in this direction if you think this would work with carto-css.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is not property in CartoCSS that allows you to do that. [Here](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/cartocss/properties/#text) you have all CartoCSS attributes related to text/labels. Maybe a better alternative is using Mapbox Studio to style/customize your basemap (and then use this basemap on other web mapping platform such as CARTO or just Leaflet), creating your own custom [fonts](https://www.mapbox.com/help/add-custom-fonts/) or [labels](https://www.mapbox.com/help/customize-label-text/).